# Got Invalid argument type error when connect to redis container

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I'm playing with `docker` and `redis` and I want to start redis from the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis):

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 redis
1:C 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.410 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.410 # Redis version=7.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.410 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.410 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.411 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.411 # Server initialized
1:M 02 Oct 2022 08:11:14.412 * Ready to accept connections
```

In my nodejs application I try to connect to the container but it failed and I got this error:

```
➜  red node app
connect!!! Promise { <pending> }
/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/encoder.js:17
            throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
                  ^

TypeError: Invalid argument type
    at encodeCommand (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/encoder.js:17:19)
    at RedisCommandsQueue.getCommandToSend (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/commands-queue.js:187:45)
    at Commander._RedisClient_tick (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:440:76)
    at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:424:82)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:170:154)
    at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as set] (/Users/user/myapp/red/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
    at /Users/user/myapp/red/app.js:17:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

This is my code:

```
(async () => {
  const redis = require("redis");
  const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 6379,
    },
    // password: '<password>'
  });

  client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error " + err);
  });

  await client.connect();

  client.set("bla", true);
  const y = client.get("bla");

  console.log("connect!!!", y);
})();
```

Why I can't able to connect to redis container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set strings or numbers:

```
client.set("bla", true);
```

should be

```
client.set("bla", "true");
```